# How to reference found matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having a small problem with a regexp pattern. I don't have regexp knowledge, so I couldn't solve it.

I have this text:

```
var text = "this (is) some (ran)dom text";
```

and I want to capture anything between `()`. So after following [this tutorial](http://regexone.com/lesson/0) I came up with this pattern:

```
var re = /(\(\w*\))/g;
```

which works fine. But what I want to do now is replace the found matches, or rather modify. I want to wrap the found matches with a span tag. So I used this code:

```
var spanOpen = '<span style="color: silver;">';
var spanClose = '</span>';
text.replace(re, spanOpen + text.match(re) + spanClose);
```

even though the code works, I don't get the result I want. It outputs:

as HTML

```
this <span style="color: silver;">(is),(ran)</span> some <span style="color: silver;">(is),(ran)</span>dom text
```

as text

```
this (is),(ran) some (is),(ran)dom text
```

You can check the example in [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XXtVb/). How can I fix this?

---

The code in fiddle:

```
var text = "this (is) some (ran)dom text";

var re = /(\(\w*\))/g;

var spanOpen = '<span style="color: silver;">';
var spanClose = '</span>';

var original = "original: " + text + "<br>";
var desired = "desired: this " +spanOpen+"(is)"+spanClose+ " some " +spanOpen+"(ran)"+spanClose+ "dom text<br>";
var output = "output: " + text.replace(re, spanOpen + text.match(re) + spanClose);

var result = original + desired + output;

document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

*<sub>If the title is wrong or misleading, I'll change it.</sub>*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.replace()` method can take a function as the 2nd parameter.  That will come in handy here.

```
var output = "output: " + text.replace(re, function(match){
    return spanOpen + match + spanClose
});
```

The function will be called for each individual match.

You can also use `'$&'` in your replace string to reference each match

```
var output = "output: " + text.replace(re, spanOpen + '$&' + spanClose);
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1):

text.match(re) is returning an array of the result, so what you can do is loop this array and replace your string with each items, like this:

```
var matches = text.match(re);

var output = "output: " + text;

for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++)
{
    output = output.replace(matches[i], spanOpen + matches[i] + spanClose);    
}
```

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XXtVb/1/)**